# Conexão externa JSON WebService

Tags: php, javascript, json, apache-cordova

Tenho um webservice em PHP alimentando dados de uma `array` via `JSON`, para leitura em um arquivo HTML.

Quando rodo a aplicação tendo o `$.get` com um arquivo local ele funciona, porém quando altero o caminho para ler o mesmo arquivo no meu servidor, ele não conecta.

Percebi no console que há um impedimento para conexões via localhost.

Levando em consideração que esta aplicação será rodará a partir da base `PhoneGap`, qual seria a melhor alternativa para tratar este problema?

Answer (score 1):

ta rodando só localhost né? então o problema talvez seja porque não esteja liberando o cross-domain, tem que permitir o acesso externo no cabeçalho:

```
<php>
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

http://leocaseiro.com.br/acesso-externo-php-ajax-crodomain/

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema é muito comum em webservices sugiro que você estudo sobre CORS http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

Esse é um problema que tem que ser resolvido tanto no servidor quanto em sua aplicação cliente sendo ela um JS ou outro cliente.

Para resolver isso no servidor você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, é só chamar essa função php no seu input file

```php
  function cors() {

// permite para qualquer origem
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache por 1 dia
}

// Essa parte cuida do preflight request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {


    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type");

    exit(0);
}

echo "Você está com CORS!";
}
```

Lembrando que não é legal você acessar variáveis globais como a $_SERVER diretamente recomendo fortemente alguma pacote php que faça isso, se possível uma framework ou mini framework para esse serviço https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-foundation já ajuda.

Para resolver isso do lado cliente é só ativar o CORS no jquery ou no http do angular no qual você preferir

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/minha/acao/",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {conteudopost: "algumacoisa"},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          //sucesso
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            //erro
        }
    });
```

Basicamente é isso qualquer dúvida deixa um comentário ai, vlw

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso o ?callback=? para poder acessar webservices json fora do domínio local.
Exemplo a baixo.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $.getJSON("http://dominioexterno.com/caminho-do-get/?callback=?", function(exemplo){

        //o que voce quer fazer.

     });
  });  
</script>
```

Há também a opção do JSONP, dar uma olhada nesse link aqui: [Jquery Cross-Domain ajax call using JSONP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667387/Jquery-Cross-Domain-ajax-call-using-JSONP)

Comment: André obrigado pela resposta, mas eu já estou usando este método. O mesmo funciona quando o arquivo está local e ler um arquivo local, ou quando está no servidor e ler um arquivo no servidor. O meu problema é quando a requisição é feita a partir do server local para o servidor web.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("http://www.tassionoronha.com.br/peixes.php",
function(data){
$("#resposta1").html(data.texto)
}, "json");
 
});
</script>
<div id="resposta1"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Acabei migrando para o Angular.js e adotando o CORS mais estruturado para servir a minha aplicação.